# Plot of igraph: how to highlight a set of vertices

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with the igraph package in `R` to highlight a set of vertices. E.g. in

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                        "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                           "David", "Esmeralda"),
                    to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
plot(g)
```

how can I highlight vertices `Bob` and `David` in the plot? In general, how can I highlight vertices that are enclosed in a vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can highlight by changing the color of the vertices.

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
plot(g)

############
highlight.these=c("Bob","David")
vertex.attributes(g)$color=ifelse(vertex.attributes(g)$name%in%highlight.these,"yellow","white")
plot(g)
```